# Force close: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public in fragment view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, background

I am facing the following issue.
When I run my app it works normally, but when I click the home Button and my app runs in background, when after a while I re-open app it's foreclosed with this notification:

```
Make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.
```

I tried this code :

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class TabHomeFragment extends Fragment implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks,
        InteractiveScrollView.OnScroll, InteractiveScrollView.OnBottomReachedListener,
        InteractiveScrollView.OnTopReachedListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private String s;
    private ArrayList<Post> arrData;
    private ArrayList<Post> arrDatanew = new ArrayList<Post>();
    private HomeAdapter adapter;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listPostMarked = new ArrayList<>();
    RelativeLayout header;
    ObservableListView lv;
    int checkPage;
    Boolean isMenuHide = false;
    InteractiveScrollView scrollview;
    private ArrayList<Post> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageView ivUp;
    ObservableScrollViewCallbacks scrollBack;
    View footer;
    ImageView imgLoad;
    private String tableName;

    public TabHomeFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public TabHomeFragment(String s, ArrayList<Post> arrData, ArrayList<Post> listArray,
                           String tableName, ObservableScrollViewCallbacks scrollBack) {
        this.s = s;
        this.arrData = arrData;
        this.listArray = listArray;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.scrollBack = scrollBack;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("LOGTAG", "On Create Home ");
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_gridview_layout, container, false);
       return view;
}
```

But it does not run.
How to do fix it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

remove empty constructor or super() you have declared

```
public TabHomeFragment() {
        super();
    }
```

use interface as follows for

Any fragment that should pass data back to its containing activity should declare an interface to handle and pass the data. Then make sure your containing activity implements those interfaces. For example:

In your fragment, declare the interface...

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}
```

Then, connect the containing class' implementation of the interface to the fragment in the onAttach method, like so:

OnDataPass dataPasser;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}
```

Within your fragment, when you need to handle the passing of data, just call it on the dataPasser object:

```
public void passData(String data) {
    dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
}
```

Finally, in your containing activity which implements OnDataPass...

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG","hello " + data);
}
```

Comment: how do I get data,interface input from activity?

Comment: just create one more method in interface  public void getData(ArrayList<Objecte>());

Comment: My mean is arraylist push from activity TabHomeFragment tab0 = new TabHomeFragment(ArrayList<Object>);
If I create empty constructor fragment How I can push arraylist from activity to fragment?